# How to allow user to Dynamically order columns in power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Before

`code`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZOWL.png)

After

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ognt1.png)